# How to fix 'Permission denied'?

Tags: android

I'm trying to save my bitmap to a file, but the android studio throws an exception `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/savedBitmap.png (Permission denied)`
What am I doing wrong?

```
public void save(){
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "savedBitmap.png");
        if (file.exists()){
            Log.i(TAG, "file is exists");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "file is not exists");
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            } finally {
                if (fos != null) fos.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```
    2019-04-30 13:03:03.058 22470-22470/com.example.paint I/PaintView: file is not exists
    2019-04-30 13:03:03.059 22470-22470/com.example.paint W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/savedBitmap.png (Permission denied)
```

Comment: have you added android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to you AnroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: yes, I have such permission

Comment: add Runtime Permission for sdk above marshmallow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first add android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to your AndroidManifest.xml. Then programmaticaly you need to check whether these permissions are enabled in your activity's onCreate() method. You can do it as follows.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        List<Integer> lPermission = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> stringPermissionList1 = getPermissionList();
        for (int i = 0; i < stringPermissionList1.size(); i++) {
            lPermission.add(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, stringPermissionList1.get(i)));
        }
        boolean bPermissionDenied = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < lPermission.size(); i++) {
            int a = lPermission.get(i);
            if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED == a) {
                bPermissionDenied = true;
                break;
            }
        }


        if (bPermissionDenied) {


            String sMessage = "Please allow all permissions shown in upcoming dialog boxes, so that app functions properly";
   //make request to the user         
List<String> stringPermissionList = getPermissionList();
            String[] sPermissions = stringPermissionList.toArray(new String[stringPermissionList.size()]);

            //request the permissions
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(sPermissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        } else {
           doFurtherProcessing();
        }


    } else {
      doFurtherProcessing();

    }
}



private List<String> getPermissionList(){
    List<String> stringPermissionList=new ArrayList<>();

 stringPermissionList.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    stringPermissionList.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    return  stringPermissionList;
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        boolean isAllPermissionGranted = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
            int iPermission = grantResults[i];
            if (iPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                isAllPermissionGranted = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isAllPermissionGranted) {
            doFurtherProcessing();
        } else {
            // Prompt the user to grant all permissions
        }

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: what doing method "doFurtherProcessing()" ?

Comment: The method doFurtherProcessing () should be written by you. I have written the code so that the program makes a request to the user to grant permissions for reading and writing to external storage. After user grants it, doFurtherProcessing () method gets called in my program. You have to write all the code that gets processed after recieving permissions in doFurtherProcessing () method.

Comment: very good. thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Runtime Permission

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, " Allow the Storage Permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_CONSTANT);
                    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm use WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Comment: What does this code do and where to insert it?

Comment: Since Marshmallow, Android needs to seek permission from the user explicitly, whether the app should use the permission or not. Such permissions are called Dangerous permissions.Please google on "Dangerous permissions" for android. And how to enable them.